# How to update an element in set which is inside another Set?

Tags: java

I have two classes as follows:

```
public class State {
    private static long count = 0;
    private long StateNo;
    private Set<Arc> arcs;
}

public class Arc {
    private char charecter;
    private State destState;
    private Set<String> letters;
}
```

Now the Class Lexicon has set of states and every state in turn has a set of arcs. My question is how to update a particular arc in the set of arcs in the particular state in the set states? (Update meaning I need to add a letter to the set of letters in that arc.)

Comment: Do you have a reference to the state you need to update?

Comment: A correct state can be identified by the stateNo, count is the static variable which keeps the stateNo unique.

Comment: In that case, I agree with the answers recommending use of Map. More specifically, you should have a Map<Long,State> that you can use to find a State given its stateNo. Similarly, you need to decide how to find the Arc you want to change, given a State.

Comment: How do you identify particular arc? Is `charecter` field uniqe?

Comment: Yes, the character field is unique

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The Arc has unique charecter for every state.

Comment: How do I update a particular Arc when I find it in a particular State in the set of States?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public class Lexicon {
    class State {
        public long count = 0;
        public long stateNo;
        public Set<Arc> arcs;
    }

    class Arc {
        public char character;
        public State destState;
        public Set<String> letters;
    }

    Set<State> states = new HashSet<State>();

    public void update(long stateNo, char character, String letter) {
        for (State state : states) {
            if(state.stateNo == stateNo) {
                for (Arc arc : state.arcs) {
                    if (arc.character == character) {
                        arc.letters.add(letter);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If so, you better rewrite it using map collection:

```
public class Lexicon {
    class State {
        public long count = 0;
        public long stateNo;
        public Map<Character, Arc> arcs;

        public void updateArc(char character, String letter) {
            Arc arc = arcs.get(character);
            if (arc != null) {
                arc.letters.add(letter);
            }
        }
    }

    class Arc {
        public char character;
        public State destState;
        public Set<String> letters;
    }

    Map<Long, State> states = new HashMap<Long, State>();

    public void update(long stateNo, char character, String letter) {
        State state = states.get(stateNo);
        if (state != null) {
            state.updateArc(character, letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this is draft only and you heave to initialize all collections.
Also all fields are declared as public only for clarity of example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of mutable objects.

One issue to be aware of is that, if changing `Arc.letters` can affect the outcome of `Arc.equals()`, you must be careful when using a `Set<Arc>`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

In particular, this means that you have to remove the element from `State.arcs`, modify it, and then re-insert it into `State.arcs`.

From your question, it would seem that you'd be better off making `arcs` a `Map` rather than a `Set`. For one thing, you'd be able to look things up by key, which is something you currently can't do.

Comment: How will I store the Arcs in a Map, I mean, what will be the key and the value? How will it help in accessing the elements? Do I have to store the States in Map as well in the Lexicon class?

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is not a direct access collection.

I think it's better for you to use `HashMap` instead of those `set`s, where you can get object by key directly.

Comment: How will I store the Arcs in a Map, I mean, what will be the key and the value? How will it help in accessing the elements? Do I have to store the States in Map as well in the Lexicon class?

Comment: You can add key property and make it unique. If you need to access an object in collection this way, you should use Map and see how to adjust your code to it. How do you identify which arc and state to update?

Comment: If you notice, the State class has a stateNo as one variable which will help find the unique State. The count variable in State class is static and takes care of the unique stateNo. Arc is represented by a  single charecter string. Every State will have an arc with unique charecter string between a-z. I am actually building a lexicon for scrabble by using the GADDAG algorithm. The algorithm is  explained with pseudo code here http://www.ericsink.com/downloads/faster-scrabble-gordon.pdf

Comment: This is quite long... Can you explain how you get to the specific state (or act) object? you iterate over all and look for something?

Comment: every State has the unique stateNo and every Arc has unique charecter of type string. I am trying to access the State and Acr using these conventions.

Comment: So you do have a unique field (stateNo for states, character for arc)? you can use it as a key to the map!